# Why does adding a double click command disable my datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, prism

I have this XAML code:

```
<DataGrid>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddedSelectedClaimsCommand}" TriggerParameterPath="AddedItems" />
      <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RemovedSelectedClaimsCommand}" TriggerParameterPath="RemovedItems" />                                
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
      <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewDetailsCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu >
      <MenuItem Header="View details" Command="{Binding ViewDetailsCommand}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

It works fine without the MouseDoubleClick EventTrigger. But when I added in the double click ability, the data grid suddenly appeared greyed out and rows could no longer be selected. Why?

Comment: What does ViewDetailsCommand definition and initialization looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canExecuteMethod delegate must be returning false for some reason, review your ViewModel and make sure all bellow is in place for you:

In you command initialization make sure you set canExecuteMethod delegate as well as your command action:

```
ViewDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteViewDetailsCommand, 
    CanExecuteViewDetailsCommand);
```

Then goes your logic that verify if preconditions are met to execute this command. At the end it will enable or disable the associated control(s) for this command.

```
private bool CanExecuteViewDetailsCommand() {       
    return null != SelectedDetail;
}
```

If command successfully passed preconditions tests, then it can safely execute  its method:

```
private void ExecuteViewDetailsCommand()
{    
    NavigateTo("DetailView",SelectedDetail);
}
```

You should have SelectedDetail property in place too (read/write):

```
Detail selectedDetail;
public Detail SelectedDetail 
{
    get { return selectedDetail; }
    set { 
        SetProperty(ref selectedDetail, value); 
        RaiseCanExecuteEvents(); 
    }
}
```

Note above RaiseCanExecuteEvents method invokation, this is a convenience method where you can force related commands validations:

```
protected virtual void RaiseCanExecuteEvents()
{
    ViewDetailsCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```